# ifort not parallelizing code

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, intel-fortran

Why does ifort not parallelize this code?
It keeps saying "loop was not parallelized: existence of parallel dependence". I can't understand where the dependence is. gfortran will generate parallel code, but the speed up is not very high.

```
PROGRAM erat
IMPLICIT NONE

INTEGER*8 :: i, rm, sn=1000000000
LOGICAL*1 , ALLOCATABLE, DIMENSION(:) :: nums

rm = INT( DBLE(sn)**0.5) + 1

ALLOCATE(nums(sn))
nums = .TRUE.                       !This line not parallelized

PRINT *, 'Doing initial sieve...'
nums(1) = .FALSE.
DO i = 2,rm
    nums(i**2:sn:i) = .FALSE.       !This line not parallelized
END DO
END PROGRAM erat
```

Comment: Even though you can't parallelise it this way, you can still do a masked assignment as `forall(j = i**2:sn:i, nums(j)) nums(j) = .FALSE.`, or `do concurrent`. It should be a bit faster that way, as there is a smaller set of indices to go through after each step of the outer loop.

Comment: Thanks, would this go inside the main do loop?

Comment: Indeed, instead of the `nums(i**2:sn:i) = .FALSE.`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That diagnostic is reported against the DO statement.  As one specific example:

- When i is 2, the loop sets num(8) to false.
- When i is 4, the loop also sets num(8) to false.

That's two different iterations of the loop writing to the same memory location.

(The relevant Intel forums are a better place to ask questions that might get into the specifics of the behaviours of their compilers.)

Comment: Since they are both writing the same value, and not reading the value, wouldn't concurrency not be an issue?

Comment: I suspect (I don't know) that goes into considerations/levels of detail beyond what the dependency analyser deals with.  (Similarly, it could be argued that all the compiler needed to do was to spit out the code associated with the print statement, since that's the only visible effect that your example has, but that analysis was beyond it too.)

Comment: Multiple concurrent writes to the same location -- even of the same value -- gives undefined behaviour and the compiler is correct to avoid it.